# Python - Calculate the number of steps between two points

Tags: python

Assuming two points, `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, how do we find the minimum number of steps required to reach `(x2, y2)` from `(x1, y1)`, assuming we can move vertically, horizontally or diagonally?

I have the following code that produces this result, but does so slowly. I'd like this result in O(1). How can I do this, preferably without using libraries?

```
def _dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    steps = 0
    while (x1, y1) != (x2, y2):
        dX, dY = calculate_delta(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        (x1, y1) = (x1 + dX, y1 + dY)
        steps += 1
    return steps


def calculate_delta(s_i, s_j, e_i, e_j):
    i = 0 if s_i == e_i else -1 if e_i < s_i else 1
    j = 0 if s_j == e_j else -1 if e_j < s_j else 1
    return i, j
```

Comment: You can't do this in constant time, unless you have precomputed routes stored in a table somewhere (or if the grid size is fixed). Constant time doesn't mean "fast", it means "independent of the input size".

Comment: In your code however it looks like a diagonal step is counted as a horizontal/vertical step, is it right?

Comment: yes you could move from (2, 2) to (1, 1) in a single diagonal step

Comment: I think I'm assuming an incomplete graph. To confirm, you can *always* move to any adjacent point (with integer coordinates)?

Comment: no, the points are all contained in a finite grid, such as a chessboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The min steps is just the greatest difference in a single axis

```
def dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return max(abs(x1 - x2), abs(y1 - y2))
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming he could move diagonally the answer is:

```py
def _dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return max(abs(x1 - x2),abs(y1 - y2))
```

That's because he would do diagonally as many steps as there are units on the shortest axis plus as many steps as the difference in length between the axes: `min + max - min = max`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple use math function, it will take O(1):

```
def _dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return max(abs(x1 - x2),abs(y1 - y2))
```

Comment: This assumes you only move horizontally or vertically, not diagonally.

Comment: Hi there, for future reference, please do not do as you have done (delete your comment because it was initially incorrect, then subsequently edit and re-publish with the accepted solution, leading to a confusing scenario for readers).

Comment: Yeah , Sorry I won't do it again

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
def _dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return max(abs(x1-x2), abs(y1-y2))
```